# How to pass the href variable to the switch case?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have four links  which are redirected on the same page only there variables are different for. So:

```
<a href="?type=square">Square</a>
<a href="?type=circle">Circle</a>
<a href="?type=triangle">Triangle</a>
<a href="?type=rectangle">Rectangle</a>
```

I want to write a switch case to pass the href variables so, that if the type is square, it should alert me, that it is a square and similarly for the others using jquery.

Comment: Please take a look to a documentation before posting a question. You can read about switch structure here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: `href` is not a variable, it is an attribute of the `<a>` tag :)

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your page is .php page

```
$optArr = array('Square','Circle','Triangle','Rectangle');

foreach($optArr as $opt)
{
   echo "<a href='tab1.php?type=".strtolower($opt).'">".$opt."</a>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said all four links will redirect to the same page, but it shows tab1.php, tab1.php, tab2.php, and tab3.php. Anyway, you can do this:

```
<a href="tab1.php?type=square">Square</a>
<a href="tab1.php?type=circle">Circle</a>
<a href="tab1.php?type=triangle">Triangle</a>
<a href="tab1.php?type=rectangle">Rectangle</a>
```

tab1.php

```
<?php
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    switch ($type) {
        case "square": echo "Square"; break;
        case "circle": echo "Circle"; break;
        case "triangle": echo "Triangle"; break;
        case "rectangle": echo "Rectangle"; break;
        default: echo "None";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP`, you can do it like this,

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){

   $type = $_GET['type'];   // get the type from the url

   switch($type){

     case 'square':
        echo 'square';
        break;
     case 'circle':
        echo 'square';
        break;
     case 'triangle':
        echo 'square';
        break;
     case 'rectangle':
        echo 'square';
        break;
     default:
        echo 'not';
   }
}
```